# Generating HashSet of objects while making hibernate reverse engineering in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, reverse-engineering

I have two tables in SQL Server database; Equipe and Ordre_de_prod table. the ordre_de_prod table contains the id of Equipe as foreign key, whenever i make hibernate reverse engineering in eclipse, the OrdreDeProd class contains an object of Equipe class. But,  I get the equipe class with a HashSet of objects of OrdreDeProd.
How cant I solve this problem ?

thank You

Answer (score 0):

While generation objects, remove many-to-many and one-to-one associations as per the attached image.[image: I think you need to remove(un-check) highlighted option.]

Comment: I unchecked the many-to-many and one-to-one association but i receive the same classes. the same problem